# Why are functions in OCaml/F# not recursive by default?

Tags: f#, recursion, ocaml

Why is it that functions in F# and OCaml (and possibly other languages) are not by default recursive?

In other words, why did the language designers decide it was a good idea to explicitly make you type `rec` in a declaration like:

```
let rec foo ... = ...
```

and not give the function recursive capability by default?  Why the need for an explicit `rec` construct?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739628/whats-the-reason-of-marking-a-recursive-function-as-rec-in-f

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The French and British descendants of the original ML made different choices and their choices have been inherited through the decades to the modern variants. So this is just legacy but it does affect idioms in these languages.

Functions are not recursive by default in the French CAML family of languages (including OCaml). This choice makes it easy to supercede function (and variable) definitions using `let` in those languages because you can refer to the previous definition inside the body of a new definition. F# inherited this syntax from OCaml.

For example, superceding the function `p` when computing the Shannon entropy of a sequence in OCaml:

```
let shannon fold p =
  let p x = p x *. log(p x) /. log 2.0 in
  let p t x = t +. p x in
  -. fold p 0.0
```

Note how the argument `p` to the higher-order `shannon` function is superceded by another `p` in the first line of the body and then another `p` in the second line of the body.

Conversely, the British SML branch of the ML family of languages took the other choice and SML's `fun`-bound functions are recursive by default. When most function definitions do not need access to previous bindings of their function name, this results in simpler code. However, superceded functions are made to use different names (`f1`, `f2` etc.) which pollutes the scope and makes it possible to accidentally invoke the wrong "version" of a function. And there is now a discrepancy between implicitly-recursive `fun`-bound functions and non-recursive `val`-bound functions.

Haskell makes it possible to infer the dependencies between definitions by restricting them to be pure. This makes toy samples look simpler but comes at a grave cost elsewhere.

Note that the answers given by Ganesh and Eddie are red herrings. They explained why groups of functions cannot be placed inside a giant `let rec ... and ...` because it affects when type variables get generalized. This has nothing to do with `rec` being default in SML but not OCaml.

Comment: I don't think they are red herrings: if it wasn't for the restrictions on inference, it's likely that entire programs or modules would be automatically treated as mutually recursive like most other languages do. That would make the specific design decision of whether or not "rec" should be required moot.

Comment: "...automatically treated as mutually recursive like most other languages do". BASIC, C, C++, Clojure, Erlang, F#, Factor, Forth, Fortran, Groovy, OCaml, Pascal, Smalltalk and Standard ML don't.

Comment: C/C++ only require prototypes for forward definitions, which isn't really about marking recursion explicitly. Java, C# and Perl certainly do have implicit recursion. We could get into an endless debate about the meaning of "most" and the importance of each language, so let's just settle for "very many" other languages.

Comment: "C/C++ only require prototypes for forward definitions, which isn't really about marking recursion explicitly". Only in the special case of self-recursion. In the general case of mutual recursion, forward declarations are mandatory in both C and C++.

Comment: Actually forward declarations are not required in C++ in class scopes, i.e. static methods are fine to call each other without any declarations.

Answer (score 55):

One crucial reason for the explicit use of `rec` is to do with Hindley-Milner type inference, which underlies all staticly typed functional programming languages (albeit changed and extended in various ways).

If you have a definition `let f x = x`, you'd expect it to have type `'a -> 'a` and to be applicable on different `'a` types at different points. But equally, if you write `let g x = (x + 1) + ...`, you'd expect `x` to be treated as an `int` in the rest of the body of `g`.

The way that Hindley-Milner inference deals with this distinction is through an explicit *generalisation* step. At certain points when processing your program, the type system stops and says "ok, the types of these definitions will be generalised at this point, so that when someone uses them, any free type variables in their type will be *freshly* instantiated, and thus won't interfere with any other uses of this definition."

It turns out that the sensible place to do this generalisation is after checking a mutually recursive set of functions. Any earlier, and you'll generalise too much, leading to situations where types could actually collide. Any later, and you'll generalise too little, making definitions that can't be used with multiple type instantiations.

So, given that the type checker needs to know about which sets of definitions are mutually recursive, what can it do? One possibility is to simply do a dependency analysis on all the definitions in a scope, and reorder them into the smallest possible groups. Haskell actually does this, but in languages like F# (and OCaml and SML) which have unrestricted side-effects, this is a bad idea because it might reorder the side-effects too. So instead it asks the user to explicitly mark which definitions are mutually recursive, and thus by extension where generalisation should occur.

Comment: Err, no. Your first paragraph is wrong (you're talking about the explicit use of "and" and not "rec") and, consequently, the rest is irrelevant.

Comment: I'd consider "rec" as a special case of "rec...and...and...", i.e. one with zero "and"s. This makes single recursion a special case of mutual recursion. As you say in your answer, SML doesn't use "rec" but does have "and", so an alternative view is to consider them to be orthogonal.

Comment: I was never pleased with this requirement. Thanks for the explanation. Another reason why Haskell is superior in design.

Comment: How exactly can side-effects be reordered during dependency analysis?

Comment: NO!!!! HOW COULD THIS HAPPEN?! This answer is plain wrong! Please read Harrop's answer below or check out _The Definition of Standard ML_ (Milner, Tofte, Harper, MacQueen -- 1997)[p.24]

Comment: As I said in my answer, the type inference issue is *one* of the reasons for the need for rec, as opposed to being the only reason. Jon's answer is also a very valid answer (apart from the usual snide comment about Haskell); I don't think the two are in opposition.

Comment: How can a function definition have a side effect? Are you talking about things like `let f = (side_effect; fun x => x)`, i.e. definitions that don't use function definition syntax? Because I assume most people would be fine with only functions that are defined using function definition syntax being allowed to be mutually recursive. That's how most other languages work.

Comment: "the type inference issue is one of the reasons for the need for rec". The fact that OCaml requires `rec` but SML does not is an obvious counter example. If type inference were the issue for the reasons you describe, OCaml and SML could not have chosen different solutions as they did. The reason is, of course, that you are talking about `and` in order to make Haskell relevant.

Answer (score 11):

There are two key reasons this is a good idea:

First, if you enable recursive definitions then you can't refer to a previous binding of a value of the same name.  This is often a useful idiom when you are doing something like extending an existing module.

Second, recursive values, and especially sets of mutually recursive values, are much harder to reason about then are definitions that proceed in order, each new definition building on top of what has been already defined.  It is nice when reading such code to have the guarantee that, except for definitions explicitly marked as recursive, new definitions can only refer to previous definitions.

Answer (score 5):

Some guesses:

- `let` is not only used to bind functions, but also other regular values. Most forms of values are not allowed to be recursive. Certain forms of recursive values are allowed (e.g. functions, lazy expressions, etc.), so it needs an explicit syntax to indicate this.
- It might be easier to optimize non-recursive functions
- The closure created when you create a recursive function needs to include an entry that points to the function itself (so the function can recursively call itself), which makes recursive closures more complicated than non-recursive closures. So it might be nice to be able to create simpler non-recursive closures when you don't need recursion
- It allows you to define a function in terms of a previously-defined function or value of the same name; although I think this is bad practice
- Extra safety? Makes sure that you are doing what you intended. e.g. If you don't intend it to be recursive but you accidentally used a name inside the function with the same name as the function itself, it will most likely complain (unless the name has been defined before)
- The `let` construct is similar to the `let` construct in Lisp and Scheme; which are non-recursive. There is a separate `letrec` construct in Scheme for recursive let's

Comment: "Most forms of values are not allowed to be recursive. Certain forms of recursive values are allowed (e.g. functions, lazy expressions, etc.), so it needs an explicit syntax to indicate this". That is true for F# but I'm not sure how true it is for OCaml where you can do `let rec xs = 0::ys and ys = 1::xs`.

Answer (score 4):

Given this:

```
let f x = ... and g y = ...;;
```

Compare:

```
let f a = f (g a)
```

With this:

```
let rec f a = f (g a)
```

The former redefines `f` to apply the previously defined `f` to the result of applying `g` to `a`. The latter redefines `f` to loop forever applying `g` to `a`, which is usually not what you want in ML variants.

That said, it's a language designer style thing.  Just go with it.

Answer (score 1):

A big part of it is that it gives the programmer more control over the complexity of their local scopes. The spectrum of `let`, `let*` and `let rec` offer an increasing level of both power and cost. `let*` and `let rec` are in essence nested versions of the simple `let`, so using either one is more expensive. This grading allows you to micromanage the optimization of your program as you can choose which level of let you need for the task at hand. If you don't need recursion or the ability to refer to previous bindings, then you can fall back on a simple let to save a bit of performance.

It's similar to the graded equality predicates in Scheme. (i.e. `eq?`, `eqv?` and `equal?`)