# Why does ocaml need both "let" and "let rec"?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [Why are functions in OCaml/F# not recursive by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900585/why-are-functions-in-ocaml-f-not-recursive-by-default)
> [What's the reason of 'let rec' for impure functional language OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796904/whats-the-reason-of-let-rec-for-impure-functional-language-ocaml)

OCaml uses `let` to define a new function, or `let rec` to define a function that is recursive. Why does it need both of these - couldn't we just use `let` for everything?

For example, to define a non-recursive successor function and recursive factorial in OCaml (actually, in the OCaml interpreter) I might write

```
let succ n = n + 1;;

let rec fact n =
    if n = 0 then 1 else n * fact (n-1);;
```

Whereas in Haskell (GHCI) I can write

```
let succ n = n + 1

let fact n =
    if n == 0 then 1 else n * fact (n-1)
```

Why does OCaml distinguish between `let` and `let rec`? Is it a performance issue, or something more subtle?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Well, having both available instead of only one gives the programmer tighter control on the scope. With `let x = e1 in e2`, the binding is only present in `e2`'s environment, while with `let rec x = e1 in e2` the binding is present in both `e1` and `e2`'s environments.

(Edit: I want to emphasize that it is *not* a performance issue, that makes no difference at all.)

Here are two situations where having this non-recursive binding is useful:

- shadowing an existing definition with a refinement that use the old binding. Something like: `let f x = (let x = sanitize x in ...)`, where `sanitize` is a function that ensures the input has some desirable property (eg. it takes the norm of a possibly-non-normalized vector, etc.). This is very useful in some cases.
- metaprogramming, for example macro writing. Imagine I want to define a macro `SQUARE(foo)` that desugars into `let x = foo in x * x`, for any expression `foo`. I need this binding to avoid code duplication in the output (I don't want `SQUARE(factorial n)` to compute `factorial n` twice). This is only hygienic if the `let` binding is not recursive, otherwise I couldn't write `let x = 2 in SQUARE(x)` and get a correct result.

So I claim it is very important indeed to have both the recursive and the non-recursive binding available. Now, the *default* behaviour of the let-binding is a matter of convention. You could say that `let x = ...` is recursive, and one must use `let nonrec x = ...` to get the non-recursive binder. Picking one default or the other is a matter of which programming style you want to favor and there are good reasons to make either choice. Haskell suffers¹ from the unavailability of this non-recursive mode, and OCaml has exactly the same defect at the type level : `type foo = ...` is recursive, and there is no non-recursive option available -- see [this blog post](https://blog.janestreet.com/ocaml-annoyance-23-type-declarations-are-implicitly-recursive/).

¹: when Google Code Search was available, I used it to search in Haskell code for the pattern `let x' = sanitize x in ...`. This is the usual workaround when non-recursive binding is not available, but it's less safe because you risk writing `x` instead of `x'` by mistake later on -- in some cases you want to have both available, so picking a different name can be voluntary. A good idiom would be to use a longer variable name for the first `x`, such as `unsanitized_x`. Anyway, just looking for `x'` literally (no other variable name) and `x1` turned a lot of results. Erlang (and all language that try to make variable shadowing difficult: Coffeescript, etc.) has even worse problems of this kind.

That said, the choice of having Haskell bindings recursive by default (rather than non-recursive) certainly makes sense, as it is consistent with lazy evaluation by default, which makes it really easy to build recursive values -- while strict-by-default languages have more restrictions on which recursive definitions make sense.

Comment: Nice post, yet I don't feel convinved by the "metaprogramming" thing. One could argue to write `square` as a function and when your compiler has inlining capabilities, this will then effectively behave like a macro, complete with alpha-renaming and all that.

Comment: In addition, the shadowing issue can be most easily done with idioms like: `foo x = work (sanitized x) where work x = ....`

Comment: @Ingo, metaprogramming is much more than just expanding generic functions.

Comment: @SK-logic: Perhaps this is why gasches example didn't convince me.

Comment: @Ingo, this example is pretty obvious if you've coded in, say, Lisp. Otherwise you have to understand the basics of metaprogramming first - any real world example would be of course much more complicated than this one.

Comment: @Ingo: your expansion idiom can be simplified to `foo x = (\x -> ...) (sanitized x)`; in other words, you are rediscovering the usual way to present `let x = e1 in e2` in untyped lambda-calculus as `(\x -> e2) e1`. This can also be applied in the macro case, eg. you'd desugar `SQUARE(foo)` into `(\x -> ...) foo`. I still prefer to be able to use `let` directly, and besides it makes a difference for typing -- at least, when local let *are* generalized.

Comment: @gasche You can also write `let work x = ...; foo x = work (sanitized x) ...` if you like that better. Hence I think the variable shadowing argument does not really hold water in the end. I can imagine that in the time ML was invented people thought that it was important to distinguish between recursive and not recursive lets, but, as others have observed, nowadays it is a bit surprising that one should annotate a function as recursive in general and in a functional language in particular.

Comment: O'Caml has a powerful module system, and ability to "open" namespaces, so that their contents get into the child scope of the "open" construct. If such a namespace gets modified to contain a definition of "x", there's already "x" in scope and scope semantics of the language are wrong, we might get some scary shadowing. Isn't `let / let rec` distinction a requirement if we want to avoid that?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I think this an independent issue. The let/letrec distinction only matters for definition of the form `let (rec)? x = e` where `e` contains references to `x`, and then the question is what that reference means, either the current definition or the previous one. Adding an `open` before that definition may shadow a previous `x` binding and change the meaning of "the previous one", but it does not change the recursive or non-recursive nature of the definition -- it introduces no more confusion than adding a `let x = foo` definition right before this line.