# OCaml writing an int list to a byte file

Tags: byte, ocaml

I'm attempting to write a list of integers to a file of bytes with the following code:

```
let out_channel = open_out_bin "G:\\JVM\\OcamlTest2.class";;

let writeBytes out_channel finalBytes = 
match finalBytes with
| [] -> close_out out_channel
| hd::tl -> output_byte out_channel hd; writeBytes out_channel tl;;
```

And I get the following error:

Error: Unbound value writeBytes

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should update your title since the problem is not about what you want to do but some syntax error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recursive functions defined with `let rec` in OCaml, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1891573/434733) for details.